# Detecting hash tag and srip the # for clean url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, hashtag

Consider the string:

```
$tring = 'e.g. i want to #sleep.';
```

Am able to check for hash tags using

```
echo preg_replace('/(#\w+)/', '\1', $tring);
```

What i want to do is send the tag without the hash in front i.e. `sleep` instead of `#sleep`

Comment: You only need to put the # out of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
echo preg_replace('/#/', '', $tring);
```

OR

```
echo preg_replace('/.+?#(.+?)/', '\1', $tring);
```